# What's the difference between System.Type and System.RuntimeType in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I was trying to do some convention tests today, and getting all the types in an assembly (by calling `Assembly.GetTypes()`), when I stumbled into something:

```
System.RuntimeType:[First.Namespace.FirstClass]
```

Whenever I try to compare that type with `typeof(FirstClass)`, they're not equal. So, when I try to find all the types that contain `FirstClass` as a generic parameter, I'm not finding any.

What's the difference between `System.RuntimeType` and `System.Type`?

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you provide a small program that demonstrates the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I was going to, but got the answer already :P

Comment: Hello from 10 years in the future! Just because you got the answer doesn't mean others wouldn't benefit from adding that context to the question...

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`System.RuntimeType` is a concrete class that derives from the abstract base class `System.Type`. Since `System.RuntimeType` is not public, you will typically encounter instances of it as `System.Type`.

Confusion can arise when you are trying to get the type of an object and mistakenly call `GetType()` on another object representing the first object's type, rather than just using that object directly. Then `Type.ToString()` will return `"System.RuntimeType"` when the object it is called on is representing a Type:

```
string str = string.Empty;
Type strType = str.GetType();
Type strTypeType = strType.GetType();
strType.ToString();     // returns "System.string"
strTypeType.ToString(); // returns "System.RuntimeType"
```

For example, in [this blog post](http://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2006/06/what-is-systemruntimetype.html) someone is trying to get the type of a column in a database, doing something like this:

```
object val = reader.GetFieldType(index);
Type runtimeType = val.GetType();
PropertyInfo propInfo = runtimeType.GetProperty("UnderlyingSystemType");
Type type = (Type)propInfo.GetValue(val, null);
```

Since val is already a Type object, val.GetType() will return another Type object representing the type `System.RuntimeTime` as this is the concrete type used to represent the original type object. The blog post then shows some unnecessary reflection trickery, to get the type of the original type object, when really all that was required was:

```
Type type = reader.GetFieldType(index) as Type;
```

So if your `Type` object is reporting that it represents a `System.RuntimeType`, make sure you have not accidentally called `GetType()` on a type you have already got.

Comment: The first code snippet only checks if the object is an instance of `Type`—it'll return true even if you pass `typeof(int)`. The second code snippet doesn't work for comparing `typeof(string).GetType()` and `typeof(Type)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I did find Thomas Danecker's post but not Doogal Bell's

Comment: @Mark Cidade. Well spotted, thanks. Have fixed answer to be more helpful, hopefully clearing up any confusion I introduced by citing that blog post.

Comment: @Edgar Gonzalez: That blog post I referenced was actually rather misleading. Please see my updated answer for better info.

Answer (score 4):

From the answer to [Different between System.Type and System.RuntimeType](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/439afe29-39cc-4026-8592-24089c4f2978/) by [Thomas Danecker](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/thomas%20danecker/):

> System.Type is an abstract base class.
>   The CLR has it's concrete
>   implementation in the internal type
>   System.RuntimeType. Because of this
>   typeof(string).GetType() returns a
>   RuntimeType but typeof(Type) returns a
>   normal Type. Using the .Equals method
>   does in fact an object.ReferenceEquals
>   which returns false. To get the
>   expecting results, you may use
>   type.IsInstanceOfType(element). This
>   will also return true if element is of
>   a derived type. If you'd want to check
>   for the exact type, the return-value
>   of false of your method is desired
>   result. You may also use
>   checkType(arrayType,
>   Type.GetType("System.RuntimeType")) to
>   check for the RuntimeType.

Comment: "does in fact an" - Can we get a grammar correction. This is like the crux of the whole thing and it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

In brief...

```
    "".GetType().ToString()           == "System.String"

    "".GetType().GetType().ToString() == "System.RuntimeType"
```

The way I now think about it is that `System.Type` is a base type for the type that represents object type request results at runtime, namely `System.RuntimeType`. So, when you request the type of an object, as in, `"".GetType()`, the instance of `System.Type` returned is it's descendent, `System.RuntimeType`. In fact, one should expect that the `typeof(System.Type).GetType()` should be `System.RuntimeType` as well, but I think the framework specifically prevents this...symmetry.