# typeof(TModels) returns RuntimeType

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, types, system.type

I need a way of getting the "true-type" of an object or a class (in this case a generic-class).. for now all I get is a RuntimeType.. I have read all over the internet but I just cant find an answer that doesnt just return a RuntimeType..

Comment: Why doesn't a `RuntimeType` suit you? What exactly do you think is the difference between “true-type” and `RuntimeType`? `RuntimeType` **is** the “true type”.

Answer (score 1):

`System.RuntimeType` is an internal concrete class that implements the abstract `System.Type` class.  See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737947/385844) to [What's the difference between System.Type and System.RuntimeType in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5737840/385844) for a good discussion.  So, you see, as svick said in his comment, `RuntimeType` *is* the true type.

You can't find a way that doesn't return a `RuntimeType` object, because `GetType()` always returns a `RuntimeType` object.  You will never be able to get a `Type` object that isn't an instance of some more-derived class, because `Type` is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

propertyinfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments() should give you a list of the generic arguments.
 It is a list because a class can have more then 1 generic.
More info here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173128.aspx 
and here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

Comment: I'm really not sure this is what's being asked.