# Conditional breakpoint on type name in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to add conditional breakpoint in `VS2015` inside `C#` method. Method signature is:

`Core(Type type, object value, bool noAutoCreate)`

The conditional expression for breakpoint is `type.Name.Contains("ltern")`

but this condition doesn't work and i receive error message

[image]

Why does it happen? How to avoid such problem and create well working conditional breakpoint if i need to catch some type ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using a conditional breakpoint on System.Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276732/error-when-using-a-conditional-breakpoint-on-system-type)

Comment: @burzhuy, What about this issue in your side? Whether it is related to the debug settings "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT i will have ability to test it only on the next week

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT thanks. When "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" is on -  i receive another error: "The function evaluation requires all threads to run"

Comment: @burzhuy, Please check that whether it is related to the debugging option "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls".https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change debugging settings. Go to `Tools->Options->Debugging->General` and check `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`

Links to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35983978/7602689) and [MSDN blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't help =( After checking, i receive another error: The function evaluation requires all threads to run

Comment: @burzhuyhave a look at [this article on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/), this case is described there.

Comment: @burzhuy, What about this issue? Please feel free to share the latest information about this issue.