# Casting in a loop using Typeof

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I stored in an array the types of 2 objects that I'm passing as arguments.
I´m trying to cast them in a loop but it doesn't seem to work.
I noticed when I debug that the value of the object's Type (returned by key.GetType()), it shows `Name=RunTimeType FullName=System.RuntimeType` instead of the expected `Name=Label`.
I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions?

```
public static void GetUserGUIDandSID(string username, Object b, Object c) { 
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
       "domainName.com");  
        UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username));
        var empIdNum = user.Guid.Value;
        var empSID = user.Sid.Value;

        List<object> types = new List<object>();
        types.Add(b.GetType());
        types.Add(c.GetType());

        foreach(var key in types) {
            if (key.GetType() == typeof(Label)) {
                ((Label)b).FontSize = 10;
                ((Label)b).Content = empIdNum;
            }
            if (key.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) {
                ((TextBox)b).FontSize = 10;
                ((TextBox)b).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
            }
            if (key.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock)) {
                ((TextBlock)b).FontSize = 10;
                ((TextBlock)b).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can just do "b is Label", "c is Label"

Comment: Could you please show us how are you calling your own function? I suspect that you are passing the type of the objects as parameter instead of their instances, as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5737947/4905310). Something like calling `GetUserGUIDandSID("user1", tb1.GetType(), lb1.GetType());` instead of `GetUserGUIDandSID("user1", tb1, lb1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly check the type of each object by using the `is` operator:

```
public static void GetUserGUIDandSID(string username, object b, object c)
{
    ...

    foreach (var o in new object[] { b, c })
    {
        if (o is Label)
        {
            ((Label)o).FontSize = 10;
            ((Label)o).Content = empIdNum;
        }
        else if (o is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)o).FontSize = 10;
            ((TextBox)o).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
        }
        else if (o is TextBlock)
        {
            ((TextBlock)o).FontSize = 10;
            ((TextBlock)o).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, you could make the method accept an arbitrary number of objects by declaring a `params object[]` argument:

```
public static void GetUserGUIDandSID(string username, params object[] objects)
{
    ...

    foreach (var o in objects)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You may now call it with different naumbers of object parameters, like

```
GetUserGUIDandSID("user", a);
GetUserGUIDandSID("user", a, b);
GetUserGUIDandSID("user", a, b, c);
```

Comment: I noticed same, but then I saw, that inside loop OP tried to cast ```b``` to every type :)

Comment: Hi Clamens thx for the insight foreach (var o in new object[] { b, c }), made my code shorter :) my problem with typeoff() was the addition GetType() in the if statement, the  'is' operator is doing the job nice, thx again

Comment: Clamens, could you please elaborate about how to make a method to accept an  arbitrary number of objects bu using 'params', this way i can generalize functions to be used in many events, lets say one time i want to pass 10 controls of different kind, other time only 3  etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Think that you wanted do this

```
List<object> types = new List<object>();
types.Add(b);
types.Add(c);

foreach (var key in types)
{
    if (key is Label)
    {
        ((Label)key).FontSize = 10;
        ((Label)key).Content = empIdNum;
    }
    if (key is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)key).FontSize = 10;
        ((TextBox)key).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
    }
    if (key is TextBlock)
    {
        ((TextBlock)key).FontSize = 10;
        ((TextBlock)key).Text = empIdNum.ToString();
    }
}
```

For OP:

Why I cnahged this 
`if (key.GetType() == typeof(Label))`
to this
`if (key is Label)`

In first case we are checking exactly `Label` type. I mean, if key will be instance of class, which derived from `Label` - first case will be false.

As example, we have custom class:

```
public class MyAwesomeLabel : Label
{
}
```

The following code

```
var myLabel = new MyAwesomeLabel();
Console.WriteLine(myLabel.GetType() == typeof(Label));
Console.WriteLine(myLabel is Label);
```

Will write `False` for first case and `True` for second.
Operator `is` in this case does not check, whether types are equal. It checks possibility to cast given instance to target type. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx .

From my perspective, in certain your case `is` is better.

Comment: Hi Tym, yes this is exactly what i wanted to do :)  btw what is the difference between 'is' and 'typeoff' in this case, both of them achieve the same result ? i made my code working with each on of them so i wonder which one of them is better