# Verification of object type to string[] is not working

Tags: c#

Can someone help me to see why my condition is not working?
To get more clear, i wish get a T type and see if this type is a string[].
In my code bellow is not matching the types, anyone can say to me what i doing wrong?

```
public T GetTotalMemoryValue<T>()
{
    object result = null;
    result = typeof(T);

    if(result.GetType() == typeof(string[]))
    {
        Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(string[]));

        try
        {  
          ...
        }
        return (T)(object) buffer;

    }
}
```

buffer is a string array.

Comment: For one, you're not returning a value... is that what you mean by "always failing"? How is the code even compiling?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What is the error?

Comment: This snippet doesn't compile at the moment, do you need help to make it compile or run? Please post a [update your question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: There is no return statement, how it is possible pass the compiling

Comment: Giving this a read may help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737840/whats-the-difference-between-system-type-and-system-runtimetype-in-c

Comment: you're essentially calling `typeof(something).GetType()`, which AFAIK will always return System.RuntimeType for any type `something`.  So why do you expect it to be equal to `typeof(string[])`

Comment: It seems the code you provided is incomplete; it will not compile since where are no return statement in `GetTotalMemoryValue()`.

Comment: I whant see if T type is string array. if it is get moving with code.

Comment: I dont put the rest of code, but i will fill with my return part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i do not know what you really want to achieve, here why the comparison is failing:

```
var result = typeof(T); // is the same as below
Type result = typeof(T);
```

`typeof()` will return a `Type` and `Type.GetType()` will always return `Type`.

The correct comparison would be:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(string[]) 
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: Not quite. typeof(string[]) is returning a System.String[] and result.GetType() is returning a System.RuntimeType.

Comment: Thanks @DangerZone i got fixed using your example. 
I didint repair the 2 returning types.

Comment: Partly. ```GetType``` will return a ```RuntimeType```, but ```typeof()``` returns also an ```RuntimeType``` containing information about the type ```string[]``` (or ```System.String[]```)