# 2 question regarding TYPE object. Does Type object is reference type? How can we create TYPE object if this is an abstract class?

Tags: c#, types, gettype

Is the `Type` object a reference type?
Let's say I have this code:

```
String s = "AAA";
Type b = s.GetType();
```

Does `b` point at a type object located on heap?

How can we create a TYPE object for an abstract class?
Again this code:

```
String s = "AAA";
Type b = s.GetType();
```

How can `s.GetType();` create a TYPE object if this is an abstract class?
You can't create instance of abstract class.

So Object.GetType() method, return a type derived from System.Type, namely System.RuntimeType - This i understand. BUT which object returns by typeof(object)? It should be a type that also derived from System.Type, since type class itself is abstract. what the name of this type?

Comment: a type of an object is not an instance of that object's class. therefore the abstract modifier does not apply to querying the type, but the fact that a class is abstract will end up as a property value of its type (`var  abstracttype = typeof(abstract_class);` then `abstracttype.IsAbstract` will be true).

Comment: System.Type is a class, so yes, it is a reference type.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The non-virtual method `Object.GetType()` is implemented by the .NET runtime. It returns the type info for the object it is called on.

The actual implementation of the returned `Type` is an implementation detail, but the .NET runtime will return a type derived from `System.Type`, namely `System.RuntimeType`. See also [What's the difference between System.Type and System.RuntimeType in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737840/whats-the-difference-between-system-type-and-system-runtimetype-in-c).

Regarding your edit:

> which object returns by `typeof(object)`?

`typeof(T)` gets compiled to `Type.GetTypeFromHandle()`, and which `Type`-derived type that method returns is an implementation detail again.

> I just want to know how is it possible to create a type object if type object is an abstract class?

You can't. The `mscorlib` library contains `public abstract class System.Type`, which `public abstract class System.TypeInfo` inherits, which in turn is inherited by `internal class RuntimeType`. So internally, the CLR does something like this:

```
public Type GetType()
{
    var typeInfo = new RuntimeType();
    // set some properties
    return typeInfo();
}
```

And because `RuntimeType` inherits from `Type`, an instance of that type can be returned from that method.

Comment: So Object.GetType() method, return a type derived from System.Type, namely System.RuntimeType - This i  understand. BUT which object returns by typeof(object)? It should be s type that also derived from System.Type, since type class is abstract. what the name of this type?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Can you please explain this again: and which Type-derived type that method returns is an implementation detail again.

Comment: An implementation detail means: you'll have to do with what the documentation states; how the runtime implements it exactly is subject to change. So like I asked under your question: what exactly do you want to know, and why? What are you going to do with the answers?

Comment: I just want to know how is it possible to create a type object if type object is an abstract class? So i understand that the type return by "gettype()" method is a derived class called "runtime type" (Runtime type) derived from the abstract class. The same i want to know about typeof() method, in this case which type class derived from type abstract class?

Comment: You can't. That's why the runtime returns a `System.RuntimeType`, which inherits from `System.Type`. You can use an abstract type as the return type for a method.

Answer (score 0):

> Does b point at a type object located on heap?

Yes, since System.Type is a reference type it is always allocated on the heap.

> How can we create a TYPE object for an abstract class?

var t = typeof(MyAbstractClass);

Answer (score -1):

You could easily get information about this on the official documentation. Please refer the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Type does not point to the actual objects. It just gets the information on the Type of the object.

As you cannot create an instance of an abstract class, you would not be able to invoke the GetType on that class.

Comment: This is a great comment but a very poor answer.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Either quote most important part of information from the link or vote to close this question