# Evaluating Boxed Type as Type in C#

Tags: c#, types, unboxing

My application uses a boxed `Type` object for which I later need to evaluate that it is of type `Type`, before unboxing.  This is implemented like so...

```
public void MyFunc(params Object[] args)
{
    Debug.Assert(args[0].GetType().Equals(typeof(Type)));
}
```

This always evaluates as false, even though I can inspect the argument in the debugger and see that it is correct.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think what you want is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression

Comment: It's probably a `RuntimeType`. See [What's the difference between System.Type and System.RuntimeType in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5737840/1715579) Also, you might want use `typeof(Type).IsAssignableFrom(args[0].GetType())` instead.

Comment: "Type" is a type itself, so maybe you rather mean `Debug.Assert(args[0].GetType().Equals(typeof(MyType)));`, where `MyType`is your specific type. Note that your line of code also returns false, if the type of `args[0]` is a class derived from `MyType`.

Comment: Adding to @p.s.w.g's comment, `args[0] is Type` will return true if `args[0]` is assignable to Type instead of checking if it is exact.

Comment: @Rhaokiel Awesome! Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566274/evaluating-boxed-type-as-type-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment99711923_56566274) pointed out, you are likely trying to compare a RuntimeType to a Type.

By using pattern matching, you can see if the object in question derives from a type like so:

```
args[0] is Type
```

[Microsoft Doc on Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression)