# Why does it return null when I try to invoke generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've been trying to execute generic methods and using recursion. The problem is that the method `GetMethod` returns `null`. How can I improve the code?

```
public static T GetElementObject<T>(this XElement element)
{
    T returnObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = returnObject.GetType().GetProperties();
    Type propertyType;

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        if (propertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseProxyEntity)))
        {
            MethodInfo getElementObject = typeof(Utility).GetMethod("GetElementObject<>", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(returnObject, getElementObject.Invoke(null, new object[] { element.Descendants(propertyInfo.Name) }), null);
        }
        else if (propertyType.IsValueType == true)
        {
            MethodInfo CastValue = typeof(Utility).GetMethod("CastValue<>", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(returnObject, CastValue.Invoke(null, new object[] { element.Attribute(propertyInfo.Name).Value }), null);
        }
        //Other else conditions ...
    }

    return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Possibly helpful link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx

Comment: Are your binding flags correct? Could you show the code for the Utility class?

Comment: There's nothing special in Utility class. It just has some static methods like the one shown above. You can see the method definition for "GetElementObject" which is called recursively.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Eugen Rieck is correct that names are mangled for generic types, they are not mangled for generic methods.  Try without the angle brackets: `GetMethod("GetElementObject", ...`  and `GetMethod("CastValue",`

Answer (score 1):

```
GetMethod("GetElementObject<>", ...)
```

Will allways return null, as there is no such method. Names are mangled for generic types, start with listing all methods and proceed from there.