# Error When Calling Intersect With Expression Tree API

Tags: c#

I am learning Expression Trees so bear with me on this one.

The idea is to call intersect an to receive the num 3.

Guess I missing something. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here please?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> arr1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<int> arr2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 3 };

        var ex =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<List<int>>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Constant(arr1), typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Intersect"), Expression.Constant(arr2)));
     ....
```

Why is this throwing that value cannot be null?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Error text is value cannot be null. I wrote it at the bottom.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it return null when I try to invoke generic methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668772/why-does-it-return-null-when-i-try-to-invoke-generic-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Intersect` is extension method, so `typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Intersect")` return null
for solve try get them from `Enumerable`

**UPDATE**

for get Intersect try this

```
var intersectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(a => a.Name == "Intersect" && a.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

better

```
var intersectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMember("Intersect").First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

Comment: Good suggestion but now I get Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match
found. Any ideas???

Comment: yes, find method that you want, `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second);` or `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer);` and get concrete

Comment: The first one shall match to what I wrote is my expression why is it still wrong?

Comment: it wrong because `GetMethod` in you case get only by name, and names same

Comment: I dont get it. Could you edit your question with the correct code please?

Comment: And why is it not working the way I wrote it down? Why do I need First() and MakeGenericMethod?

Comment: You need `First()` to specify method what you want, because `Enumerable` class has several methods with same name, you need `MakeGenericMethod` to specify generic type what you want use

Comment: I get that but is it not working with GetMethod("Intersect", new Type[] { type })?

Comment: no, for more see [GetMethod for generic method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method)