# How do I get a MethodInfo for an overloaded static method?

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, reflection

When I run:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Lambda", new Type[]{typeof(Expression), typeof(ParameterExpression[])});
```

I get:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
```

This is in an effort to do this genericly (instead of knowing it's a string)

```
var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
return entities.OrderBy(newExpression);
```

**EDIT**: Additional info:

running:

```
typeof(Expression).GetType().GetMethod("GetMethodCandidates", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(typeof(Expression),new object[]{"Lambda", BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Public, CallingConventions.Standard,new Type[]{typeof(Expression), typeof(ParameterExpression).MakeArrayType()},false})
```

returns the array:

```
[0]: {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] Lambda[TDelegate](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])}
[1]: {System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] Lambda[TDelegate](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression])}
[2]: {System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression Lambda(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])}
[3]: {System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression Lambda(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression])}
```

Comment: If you use typeof(Expression).GetMethods instead does it find more than one, and how do they differ?

Comment: I get what amounts to the list of methods inside the MSDN docs. The only thing that had any indication was a generic and non generic version of the method. But when I used the MakeGenericType() I didn't get static methods back, which is what I needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately reflection was written before generics were made available and often doesn't support generic methods/classes well at all.

Similar questions to this have been asked ([GetMethod for generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method)) where the answer has been to get the candidate methods and pick the one you want from the collection of methods.