# Using System.Type to call a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, system.reflection

I am using C#/.NET 4.0 and a Protocol Buffers library (protobuf-net) which provides the following functionality.

```
public static class Serializer {
    public static void Serialize<T>(Stream destination, T instance);
    public static void Serialize<T>(SerializationInfo info, T instance);
    public static void Serialize<T>(XmlWriter writer, T instance);
    public static void Serialize<T>(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, T instance);
    public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream source);
}
```

**I need to wrap two of these calls with non-generic equivalents.** Specifically, I want

```
void SerializeReflection(Stream destination, object instance);
object DeserializeReflection(Stream source, Type type);
```

that simply call the respective generic members of `Serializer` at runtime. **I have gotten the `DeserializeReflection` method to work with the following code:**

```
public static object DeserializeReflection(Stream stream, Type type)
{
    return typeof(Serializer)
        .GetMethod("Deserialize")
        .MakeGenericMethod(type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { stream });
}
```

The `SerializeReflection` method is what is causing me trouble. I at first tried the following code:

```
public static void SerializeReflection(Stream stream, object instance)
{
    typeof(Serializer)
        .GetMethod("Serialize")
        .MakeGenericMethod(instance.GetType())
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { stream, instance });
}
```

The problem is that the part between `typeof(Serializer)` and `.Invoke(...)` is not working. The call to `GetMethod("Serialize")` gets me an `AmbiguousMatchException`, because there are four methods named "`Serialize`."

I then tried using the overload of `GetMethod` that takes an array of `System.Type` to resolve the binding:

```
GetMethod("Serialize", new[] { typeof(Stream), instance.GetType() })
```

But this just made the result of `GetMethod` `null`.

**How can I use reflection to get the `MethodInfo` for `void Serializer.Serialize<T>(Stream, T)`, where `T` is `instance.GetType()`?**

Comment: Consider this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use next code snippet to see if it meets your need. It creates a close typed instance of method `public static void Serialize<T>(Stream destination, T instance)`. In this case it select the first method with `Stream` as parameter, but you can change this predicate `method.GetParameters().Any(par => par.ParameterType == typeof(Stream))` to whatever you want

```
public static object DeserializeReflection(Stream stream, object instance)
{
   return typeof(Serializer)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(method => method.Name == "Serialize" && method.GetParameters().Any(par => par.ParameterType == typeof(Stream)))
        .MakeGenericMethod(instance.GetType())
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { stream, instance });
}
```

Comment: While this works for this specific type where there's exactly one overload of `Serialize` that takes a `Stream`, keep in mind that more rigorous checking of the parameters should be done if you intend to generalize this method of locating the appropriate generic method definitions on a type.

Comment: @mlorbetske yes, sure. That's why I wrote to specify predicate, that meets his cretiria. Anyway - thank for comment. Your answer is also quite good.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of thing I often user helper methods like this

```
public static MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod<TSourceType>(Type genericArgument, string methodName, Type[] parameterTypes, params int[] indexesWhereParameterIsTheGenericArgument)
{
    //Get the type of the thing we're looking for the method on
    var sourceType = typeof (TSourceType);
    //Get all the methods that match the default binding flags
    var allMethods = sourceType.GetMethods();
    //Get all the methods with the same names
    var candidates = allMethods.Where(x => x.Name == methodName);

    //Find the appropriate method from the set of candidates
    foreach (var candidate in candidates)
    {
        //Look for methods with the same number of parameters and same types 
        //   of parameters (excepting for ones that have been marked as 
        //   replaceable by the generic parameter)
        var parameters = candidate.GetParameters();
        var successfulMatch = parameters.Length == parameterTypes.Length;

        if (successfulMatch)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; ++i)
            {
                successfulMatch &= parameterTypes[i] == parameters[i].ParameterType || indexesWhereParameterIsTheGenericArgument.Contains(i);
            }
        }

        //If all the parameters were validated, make the generic method and return it
        if (successfulMatch)
        {
            return candidate.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
        }
    }

    //We couldn't find a suitable candidate, return null
    return null;
}
```

To use it, you'd do

```
var serializeMethod = MakeGenericMethod<Serializer>(instance.GetType(), "Serialize", new[]{typeof(stream), typeof(object)}, 1);
```

Comment: This would also work for what I'm doing, but Mr. Ivanov's answer was very direct.