# C# Getting Type out of a string variable and using it in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, gettype

I want to be able to get the actual Type of a string value I receive by some means (i.e from database) so I can use that Type in generic method like `DoSomething<Type>()`.

In my project, I have classes `Plane`, and `Car` located in `MyCompany.MySolution.Vehicle` namespace like so

```
- MyCompany.MySolution.Vehicle
  |+Interfaces
  |-Implementations
    |-Car
    |-Plane
```

I receive type of the vehicle as a string.  So, I get string "Car" which means, I need to get Type `Car` so I can use that type in a generic method to register it like so:

```
MyFactory.Register<Car>(carId)
```

So, MyFactory is static class calling Register() method.

Similarly, I receive string "Plane" which means, I need to get Type `Plane` so I can use that type in the generic method above to register a Plane.

I tried using something like

```
MyFactory.Register<Type.GetType("MyCompany.MySolution.Vehicle.Implementations.Car")>(carId)
```

,but that does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using the fully-qualified name of `Car` (including the namespace)? i.e. `Type.GetType("MyCompany.MySolution.Vehicle.Implementations.Car")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using System.Type to call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222277/using-system-type-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @matt-dot-net No, it is not duplicate.  Rufus, yes I tried that, that wont return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invoke a Generic Method with a Type parameter generate at Runtime, you *could* do something like this:

```
var vehicleString = "Car";

// use the fully-qualified name of the type here
// (assuming Car is in the same assembly as this code, 
//  if not add a ", TargetAssemblyName" to the end of the string)
var vehicleType = 
    Type.GetType($"MyCompany.MySolution.Vehicle.Implementations.{vehicleString}");

// assuming MyFactory is the name of the class 
// containing the Register<T>-Method
typeof(MyFactory).GetMethod("Register")
    .MakeGenericMethod(vehicleType)
    .Invoke(this);
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pz0ScG)

Just as a note:

This is ***not*** how generics are supposed to be used. I'm just pointing out the possibility, not giving you an ideal answer to the problem you're proposing. Maybe you should rethink some of your architectural design choices!

Comment: I dont need to GetMethod from MyFactory.  It is a static class so I can use it just like I explained MyFactory.Register<Car>(carId).  The problem is as I explained how to get the type Car out of string "Car" so I can put that type in Register<Type>.  Putting your Register<vehicleType> errors with "vehicleType is a variable but it is used as a type" error.  That is exactly what I explained I was trying to do minus your attempt to use GetMethod.

Comment: Yes you do. You can't pass a type variable as a generic parameter without using Reflection. I just added a working example to my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `Register<T>` does something like this

```
void Register<T>(int id)
{
    _dictionary.Add(typeof(T), ...);
}
```

Create a non generic overload

```
void Register(Type t, int id)
{
    _dictionary.Add(t, ...);
}
```

This new overload is not type safe, but creating a type out of a string isn't anyway.

The purpose of generics is to gain variability (not to be confused with dynamic behavior!) while keeping type safety. But when types are determined at runtime, type safety is not given and generics are more of a hindrance than useful.

Note that type safety is ensured by the compiler, which does of course not work at runtime.

Comment: So, how do I get the Type t out of string "Car" so I can pass it into Register(Type t, int id)?  As explained, I dont know the Type, I have string value "Car" out of which I have to get Type Car :)

Comment: Use `Type.GetType`. First look into `typeof(Car).FullName` to see the exact name you must supply.

Comment: no, you cannot use Type.GetType("") inside a generic method.  You cannot do DoSomething<Type.GetType("")>(Id), that wont work

Comment: Of course not as generic type parameter, but you can do it to get a `Type` object for my second method. (This is why I suggested it).

Comment: Thanks but I need to use it as generic param, tying to figure that out but your suggestion is certainly helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary which holds all your types with strings keys:

```
var d = new Dictionary<String,Type>(); 
d.Add("Car",typeof(Car)); 
d.Add("Plane",typeof(Plane));
```

Then if you get the string "Car" from the database you can get the type like this:

```
var myType = d["Car"];
```

Then use `myType` as the real Type.

Comment: Well, my register method is trying to add it to dictionary just as you explain.  But as explained, my Register method is generic, so need to know the type to be able to call it like Register<Car>(carId)