# C# Is it possible to get actual type out of a string representing that type?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, typeof, gettype

I have string "Car", and I would like to get the type `Car` from it.  My class Car is:

```
namespace MySolution.MyProjectA
{
    public class Car
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

I trying getting type like this but it returns null:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MySolution.MyProjectA.Car"); // returns null
```

**Given a string variable representing my type (i.e. "Car"), how do I get its Type Car?**

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

Thanks to suggestion from @AsafPala here ([Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)), I got it to work.  Turns out if you are calling GetType from another project in your solution (which is another assembly), you have to provide also assembly name.

Since MySolution has 2 project MyProjectA and MyProjectB, these are 2 separate projects (or assemblies) in same solution so you need to provide fully specified assembly name of your type (that is `MySolution.MyProjectA.Car`) and assembly name (that is `MySolution.MyProjectA`) as comma separated as below:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MySolution.MyProjectA.Car,MySolution.MyProjectA");
```

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

Since I am calling this code in another project (which is same as assembly), I need to provide fully specified type name and assembly name as comma separated like so:

```
namespace MySolution.MyProjectB
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        ...
        ...
        public void MyMethod()
        {
             // this wont work, I get null back
             //Type myType = Type.GetType("MySolution.MyProjectA.Car");
             Type myType = Type.GetType("MySolution.MyProjectA.Car,MySolution.MyProjectA"); //this works
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null

Comment: Please edit your [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679223/c-sharp-getting-type-out-of-a-string-variable-and-using-it-in-generic-method) and add more details rather than asking a new one for the same question. Even this question does not show the pertinent details; you should show the `namespace` around the class (it may not be the same as `"MySolution.MyProject"`).

Comment: @RufusL The namespace is correct and I added that info, too as you asked.  The questions is as simple as it gets, not sure what else is not clear.  Plus it is simplified version of previous one (so I am not asking it again) in a way that I focus only on one thing which is getting the actual type Car out of string "Car".

Comment: Where are you calling `GetType` from? Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score -3):

Yes.  You need to serialize the object to a string first. You can use json or xml as the serializer type.

Then on the other side you use the same serializer object to deserialize the string into an instance of your class.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

```
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11

> XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List),
>   new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));
>
> StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
>
> List productList =
>   (List)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

And then after you deserialize you can get the Type of the object

Comment: This question is about getting a `Type` from a string, not serialization.

Comment: The type of any string is string.  I'm not following

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`Type.GetType(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetType_System_String_)

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood the question. But I don't seem to be able to delete the answer

Comment: Following your comment at the top, it looks like the same question and several answers are there