# Passing Type variable as a type of generic method

Tags: c#, oop, generics, reflection

I have a dictionnary that represent a association between a value type enum and a type domain entity.

```
        Dictionary<SettingType, Type> dictionnary = new Dictionary<SettingType, Type>() {
            {SettingType.GameBoard, typeof(GameBoardParameterLine)},
            {SettingType.Mountain, typeof(MountainParameterLine)},
            {SettingType.Treasure, typeof(TreasureParameterLine)},
            {SettingType.Adventurer, typeof(AdventurerParameterLine)}
        };
```

I have this following generic method that works fine:

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> CreateGroupOf<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> rawDataGroup) where T : ParameterLine
    {
        return rawDataGroup.Select(rawSettings => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), rawSettings));
    }
```

I want to call this static method by passing a variable of type "Type" retrieve from dictionnary :

```
            Type currentType = dictionnary.GetValueOrDefault(SettingType.GameBoard);
        IEnumerable<GameBoardParameterLine> parameterLineGroup = ParameterLineGroupFactory.CreateGroupOf<currentType>(data);
```

The problem is that i got cannot implicity convert exception.

I read this [Using System.Type to call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222277/using-system-type-to-call-a-generic-method) but that doesn't resolve a problem for me beacause of the return type that is "Object".

Comment: Thank but doesn't works because the return type is Object and i need a typed return type.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reflection to call CreateGroupOf with dynamic type:

```
IEnumerable parameterLineGroup = 
   typeof(ParameterLineGroupFactory)
   .GetMethod("CreateGroupOf")
   .MakeGenericMethod(currentType)
   .Invoke(null, new object[] { data }) as IEnumerable;
```

Though parameterLineGroup is untyped enumerable because currentType might be not GameBoardParameterLine.