# Unable to find private void generic function with GetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a function with the following signature:

```
private void Foo<TPoco>(IContext context, List<TPoco> pocos, DateTime modifiedDateTime)
    where TPoco : MyAbstractClass
```

And I cannot find this function in GetMethods().

Based on this SO post ( [GetMethod for generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method#7182379) ), I have tried these binding flags:

```
GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public 
    | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
    | BindingFlags.Instance 
    | BindingFlags.Static 
    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
)
```

And this finds 14 other methods in the class, but not this one. It *does* find this method:

```
protected void Bar<TContext, TPoco>(List<TPoco> pocosToPersist, TContext context)
    where TContext : IContext, new()
    where TPoco : MyAbstractClass
```

So the only difference is the access level - but then I can see other private functions.

Even if I change the binding flags to something simpler (which, from what I understand, shouldn't make **new** items visible):

```
GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance )
```

I still don't see the function.

Comment: Your last attempt should work perfectly. On what object are you calling `GetType` ?

Comment: The problem must lie somewhere else. Copy the function and reflection calls into a new project or something like .Net Fiddle and you will see that the code you posted here works flawless.

Comment: Yup, you are both right - the private function is in an abstract class, so GetType() was getting a different type than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments on the post point out, the code *should* have worked. The issue is that the class I am defining the function in is abstract, so I wasn't able to find the private function.

If I do `this.GetType().BaseType.GetMethods( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)`, the function shows up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't having an issue with the return void type, but having the same symptoms with GetMethods() - i.e. it would not return the method.
I found GetRuntimeMethods() instead, and that included the generic method I was looking for.

In terms of wider understanding and other ways to approach this - this thread (I think) is more relevant: [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)