# Why is getMethod() returning null in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
var v = xyz.GetType();    
var generic = v.GetMethod("Update", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>) });//returns null

...

public class Xyz
{
    public void Update<T>(IEnumerable<T> translations) where T : ijk
...
```

Calling `v.GetMethods()[1]` returns the correct method.

Comment: This might be a good place to start - [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: I am aware of that, but why doesn't it work in my case? afaik I'm not missing any flags/parameters

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` is an unbound generic type and is not the same thing as `IEnumerable<T>`. Your call would be the logical way to do it if `GetMethod` supported it, but it doesn't. You'll need something [more complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/).

Comment: The parameter type is `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<>`. There is a difference.

Comment: Jeroen's comment is correct. If you want the less-complicated way you can in fact change your method to make it non-generic: `public void Update(IEnumerable<ijk> translations)` because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant.