# How to determine if ParameterInfo is of generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, methodinfo, parameterinfo

I have a `MethodInfo` of a GenericMethodDefinition.  Such as: `CallMethod<T>(T arg, string arg2)`.  The GetParameters() method will give me two ParameterInfo objects, the first of which is generic, the second of which is not.  How can I get ParameterInfo to tell me it is generic?  What about if it has constraints?

Comment: thanks to the mods for creating the parameterinfo tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `ParameterType.IsGenericParameter`.
You may also want to check `ContainsGenericParameters`, which will be true for something like `MyMethod<T>(List<T> param)`.  (Even though `List<>` isn't a generic parameter)

If `IsGenericParameter` is true, you can also call `GetGenericParameterConstraints()` to get interface or base type constraints, and you can check `GenericParameterAttributes` (a `[Flags]` enum) for `new()`, `struct`, or `class` constraints.

Comment: what about generic parameter constraints?

Comment: In case `args` is an array of `T[]` one may use `ParameterType.IsArray` and `ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameter`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for these:

```
parameterInfo.ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters
parameterInfo.ParameterType.GetGenericParameterConstraints()
```

Answer (score 2):

In additional to others' answer to the second question: Yes we can get the constraints from `ParameterInfo` using `GetGenericParameterConstraints()`, but it doesn't work for all circumstances. Consider some generic method like this:

```
public static void MyMethod<T,V>() where T : Dictionary<int, int>
{
}
```

There is a constraint for this method, but the method doesn't have parameters(think about [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)). What I'm going to say is the constraint is not part of the parameters, but the method itself. We can get the constraints by:

```
method.GetGenericArguments()[0].BaseType  //the constraint of T
method.GetGenericArguments()[1].BaseType  //that of V: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2006/02/16/532996.aspx)  you will find information about reflecting generic parameters ...