# How can I use a list of types as a generic argument?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a number of types that all implement a simple interface.

I would like to be able to get a list of the types and then use them in a generic method

```
ForEach(var type in TypesThatImplement<Ifoo>){
    DoThing.Doit<type>();    
}
```

Rather than have to maintain a list of

```
DoThing.Doit<TypeA>();
DoThing.Doit<TypeB>();
DoThing.Doit<TypeC>();
```

Comment: What is your problem on doing so? What have you tried? You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738280/use-reflection-to-call-generic-method-on-object-instance-with-signature-someobj. Are all those types in the same assembly? How do you get all the implementing types? Your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a practical reason why you are doing this (maybe a small part of a larger problem?), but it is possible (see below).  If you have a more specific problem, maybe try updating your question.

```
        DoThing doThing = new DoThing();

        //loop through types which are IFoo
        foreach (var type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass))
        {
            //call DoThing.Doit<t> method using reflection
            MethodInfo method = typeof(DoThing).GetMethod("Doit");
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            generic.Invoke(doThing, null);
        }
```

Note, the above code assumes DoThing as defined:

```
public class DoThing
{
    public void Doit<T>() where T : IFoo
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The list of types that need 'Done' is long and will be longer. If  I don't have to remember to add them to the list when they are created then that is a good thing for me.