# Reflection: How to get a generic method?

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)
>   [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection)

Hi there

Let's say I have two following two methods in a class:

```
public void MyMethod(object val) {}
public void MyMethod<T>(T val) {}
```

With reflection, I could get the first Method like this:

```
Type[] typeArray = new Type[1];
typeArray.SetValue(typeof(object), 1);
var myMethod = myInstance.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod", typeArray);
```

But how can I get the second, generic method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection

Comment: @AakashM: This *is not* a duplicate of that particular question.

Comment: If the solutions to this are annoying in terms of code, a good workaround is to have a private generic method in your own code that calls the generic method you want to target, then call it using reflection in which case you can get away with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/920

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
var myMethod = myInstance.GetType()
                         .GetMethods()
                         .Where(m => m.Name == "MyMethod")
                         .Select(m => new {
                                              Method = m,
                                              Params = m.GetParameters(),
                                              Args = m.GetGenericArguments()
                                          })
                         .Where(x => x.Params.Length == 1
                                     && x.Args.Length == 1
                                     && x.Params[0].ParameterType == x.Args[0])
                         .Select(x => x.Method)
                         .First();
```

Comment: thx - didn't expect to be that complicated :-)

Comment: wow, that is amazingly annoying

Answer (score 10):

I would do it like this:

```
var methods = from m in typeof(MyClass).GetMethods()
              where m.Name == "MyMethod"
                 && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition

              let typeParams = m.GetGenericArguments()
              let normalParams = m.GetParameters()

              where typeParams.Length == 1 && normalParams.Length == 1
                 && typeParams.Single() == normalParams.Single().ParameterType
                 && !typeParams.Single().GetGenericParameterConstraints().Any()

              select m;

var myMethod = methods.Single();
```

We're looking for a method called "MyMethod" that is a generic method with a single type-parameter having no constraints, and one 'normal' parameter of the same type as the type-parameter.

Obviously, if you're not looking to be very precise, you can just do the bare minimum to disambiguate, such as:

```
var myMethod = typeof(MyClass)
              .GetMethods()
              .Single(m => m.Name == "MyMethod" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
```

Comment: thx - the second query is a nice workaround. But in may case I rather stay precise since there are more overloaded methods...