# Type.GetMethod with a Generic overload - Get Generic MethodInfo without looping through all Methods

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I Have two functions:

1. `public void DeleteRecord(int id);`
2. `public T DeleteRecord<T>(int id);`

Here's how i try to dynamically invoke the generic method:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(DAL).GetMethod("DeleteRecord", new[] { typeof(int) });
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(returnType);
object o = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbname, spname, expandoAsDictionary });
```

The first line throws an exception because it finds an ambiguous definition. Is there a way i can get the `MethodInfo` of the generic method without using `GetMethods` and looping through the results asking for `IsGenericMethod`?

Edit:
Please remove the 'Duplicate' because both of the suggested answers either solve this with an inner loop (GetMethods().Select...) or don't even address overloads.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. i already know how to call a generic method with reflection but i have an ambiguous definition exception. Please read my question through.

Comment: it's a duplicate, but I linked the wrong question, sorry... here's the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5218395/201088.

Comment: still no dup! i explicitly asked how to do it without using the GetMethods() function. the answer marked in your link is using it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the exact solution for your Problem, but maybe you could be happy with this solution:

```
var generic = typeof(BadFoo).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsStatic == true && p.Name == "DeleteRecord" && p.ReturnType == typeof(Int32));
```

I thought there would be like a "FullName" for the Method, so `GetMethod()` could be calles with a FullName to get the unique Method. But there is no other Property in Method than Name.

Comment: Please read my question through. I asked how to do this without GetMethods() :)

Comment: Like I said, this is not the exact solution. But at least you won't be "looping through the results"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll considering using it... I'm looking for a way to distinguish between the methods on a higher level as your solution still has a loop behind the scenes (FirstOrDefault)