# Type.GetMethod() Not Returning methodinfo of Templated Parameterize function

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have Overloaded methods via use of templates. GetMethod is not returning the any methodinfo for supplied types of Parameters.I Need help to identify the correct type signature needed to retrive methodinfo from following code

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyFunc<Template>(int a)
    { }
    public void MyFunc<Template>(long a)
    { }
    public void MyFunc<Template>(MyClass1<Template, int> a)
    { }
    public void MyFunc<Template>(MyClass1<Template, long> a)
    { }
}

public class MyClass1<T,G>
{ }
```

I am using it as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type[] types = new Type[] 
    {
        typeof(MyClass1<object, int>)
    };

    //Contains Required Method
    var allAvailMethods = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods();

    //required method void MyFunc<Template>(MyClass1<Template, int> a)
    //Returns NULL
    var requiredMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyFunc", types);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218492/1529246

Comment: Thanks YK1 and Stefan, those posts did solve my problem

Comment: I think you can answer your own question with code that you used to fix your exact problem and mark it as accepted, so that anyone who would find the question can solve the same problem easily.