# Differentiate generic methods by type parameters only using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to get a specific MethodInfo of a class, but am unsure how to differentiate between the two following methods:

```
public class Test
{
    public IBar<T1> Foo<T1>();
    public IBar<T1, T2> Foo<T1, T2>();
}
```

How can I get a reference to the different Foo methods, assuming I know the number of type parameters? Just calling typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo") will throw an exception that the method name is ambiguous and there aren't a differing number of parameters to check.

Comment: This can be of help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218395/reflection-how-to-get-a-generic-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get all methods then filter them based on generic argument count:

```
typeof(Test).GetMethods()
.First(x => x.Name == "Foo" && x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
```

Note that `First` method will throw an exception if there is no method that satisfies the condition.You can use `FirstOrDefault` and check for *null* instead if you want to avoid exceptions.

Comment: +1.  I would be inclined to swap the comparison clauses in the `.Where` call, though.  That way you're only calling `GetGenericArguments` for methods that have the name you're looking for.

Comment: GetGenericArguments was exactly what I couldn't find. Thanks.