# Get methodinfo for Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I'm building some Linq Expression and trying to get hold of MethodInfo for `IEnumerable.DefaultIfEmpty` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx). What seemed to be an easy task but I'm clueless to why it's not working.

```
typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("DefaultIfEmpty", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>) });

typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("DefaultIfEmpty", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(WorkitemListModel)) });
```

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection/3632196#3632196

Comment: @LukeH That was an interesting solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting generic methods is a pain, to be honest. I don't know of a better way than to use:

```
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                               .Where(m => m.Name == "DefaultIfEmpty")
                               .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
                               .Single();
```

To call `GetMethod`, you'd have to have the exact correct parameter type, including the right generic type parameter for the parameter. Once you've got that *once* you could do it, but until then I think the above is all that's available :(