# Get MethodInfo for Enumerable.First() vs MethodInfo for Enumerable.OfType()?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

- To get the [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for [`Enumerable.OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) we can use:

  ```
  typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable) })
  ```
- For the `MethodInfo` of [`Enumerable.Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) we can use the similar:

  ```
  typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethod("Sum", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<int>) })
  ```
- However, for the `MethodInfo` for ['Enumerable.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) we have to make do with:

  ```
  typeof(Enumerable).GetMember("Reverse").OfType<MethodInfo>().First()
  ```
- When the method is overloaded, for example taking a predicate, such as [`Enumerable.First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the get `MethodInfo` call becomes even more kludgy<sup>*</sup>:

  ```
  typeof(Enumerable).GetMember("First").OfType<MethodInfo>().Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1).First()
  ```

All four methods appear extension methods define in `Enumerable` that extend either `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<>`, or specific specialisations of `IEnumerable<>` such as `IEnumerable<int>`.

Why do the calls `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Reverse", new Type { typeof(IEnumerable<>)})` and `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("First", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>) })` return `null` and not a `MethodInfo`-object?  What is the difference between the first two extension methods and the latter two?

---

<sup>* : See [Get methodinfo for Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384031/814206) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384066/814206 and [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3631547)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enumerable.OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(
    this IEnumerable source
)
```

[`Enumerable.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
)
```

`OfType<>` takes an `IEnumerable`. `Reverse<>` takes an `IEnumerable<>`, not an `IEnumerable`

`Sum` expects `IEnumerable<int>`, which is possible to pass in as an argument type.

An alternative, type-safe way to get the `MethodInfo` is:

```
public MethodInfo GetMethod(Expression<Action> e)
{
    var methodCall = e.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodCall.Method.IsGenericMethod)
        return methodCall.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    return methodCall.Method;
}

var method = GetMethod(() => Enumerable.Empty<int>().First());
var overLoadedMethod = GetMethod(() => Enumerable.Empty<int>().First(a => true));
```

Note that we're getting the *generic* method, even though we've asked for the `int` template - so this will also work if you don't know the `TSource` at compile time.

Also works for types you don't have an instance of:

```
GetMethod(() => ((MyThing)null).DoSomething());
```