# How to call static method from ASP.NET MVC controller in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, system.reflection

GetMethod does not find public static method if called from ASP .NET MVC controller.
(From console application it work OK).

To solve this dummy `SaveEntityGenericWrapper` method is used.

How to remove `SaveEntityGenericWrapper` from code ?

Why `GetMethod("SaveEntityGeneric")` returns `null` but `GetMethod("SaveEntityGenericWrapper")` works
if called from ASP .NET MVC 2 controller ?

How to make `SaveEntityGeneric` private if partial trust is used in MVC2 ?

```
public class EntityBase() {

    public void SaveEntity(EntityBase original)
    { 
        var method = GetType().GetMethod("SaveEntityGenericWrapper");
        // why this line returns null if called from ASP .NET MVC 2 controller:
        // method = GetType().GetMethod("SaveEntityGeneric");
        var gm = method.MakeGenericMethod(GetType());
        gm.Invoke(this, new object[] { original, this });
    }

    // Dummy wrapper reqired for mvc reflection call only. 
    // How to remove it?
    public List<IList> SaveEntityGenericWrapper<TEntity>(TEntity original, TEntity modified)
        where TEntity : EntityBase, new()
    {
        return SaveEntityGeneric<TEntity>(original, modified);
    }

    public static List<IList> SaveEntityGeneric<TEntity>(TEntity original, TEntity modified)
                where TEntity : EntityBase, new()
    { ... actual work is performed here  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `BindingFlags` in the [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) call so that static methods are retured (I think that by default only public instance methods are returned)

```
 var method = GetType().GetMethod("SaveEntityGenericWrapper",
                                  BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: From the docs fors `GetMethod(string)`: "The search includes public static and public instance methods."

Comment: @SWeko: I added bindingflags you recommended but problem persist. Note that code works OK in console application. Issue occurs if SaveEntity method is called from .NET 3.5 MVC2 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not make problems with **private**, trying to solve bravely more complex problems.

See your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404838/how-to-call-private-generic-method-in-c-passing-type-in-runtime/) post, how simple it **was**.

At least, use

```
internal static List<IList> SaveEntityGeneric<TEntity>(TEntity original, TEntity modified)
                where TEntity : EntityBase, new()
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: In his example the `SaveEntityGeneric` method is public, at least that's what he showed in the question.

Comment: @Artur: I changed SaveEntityGeneric from public to internal and tried GetMethod on it. Problem persists. I don'nt understand your answer: if public static method is not found, how changing it to internal static enables its finding.