# Invoke Enumerable.Where (or other overloaded generic method) using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, extension-methods

There are 2 overloads (or method signatures) of the "Where" method in Enumerable class:

```
namespace System.Linq {
    public static class Enumerable {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
    }
```

So

```
var where = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where")
```

throws an exception stating  an ambiguous match because, of course, there is more than one method with the name "Where", so I tried to differentiate by the parameters:

```
var types = new[] { 
    typeof(IEnumerable<>), 
    typeof(Func<,>)};
var where = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Where", types);
```

This however doesn't match either of the method signatures, and I'm not sure why.

Generalized question: How do you invoke an overloaded generic method via reflection without iterating over all the methods in the class w/ the same name (i.e., using System.Type.GetMethod(System.String, System.Type[])?

Please help me fix it! Thanks!

Comment: typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(w=>w.Name=="Where"); works, but i just want know how to get it by Type.GetMethod(string name, Type[] types)

Comment: The Where method that takes an IQueryable and an Expression is in Queryable, not in Enumerable

Comment: @Thomas Levesque Thanks, I made a mistake!

Answer (score 5):

You can't accomplish this with only `GetMethod()` because it has limitations with generics. This is how you would do it with `GetMethod()` properly.

```
Type enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);
MemberInfo[] members = enumerableType.GetMember("Where*");
MethodInfo whereDef = (MethodInfo)members[0]; // Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource, Func<TSource,Boolean>)
Type TSource = whereDef.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // TSource is the only generic argument
Type[] types = { typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(TSource), typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(TSource, typeof(Boolean)) };
MethodInfo method = enumerableType.GetMethod("Where", types);
```

The best way is to just iterate over `members` since it already contains both `MethodInfo` definitions for `Where<TSource>`.

Comment: <!-- language: c# --> typeof (Enumerable).GetMember("Where")[0] as MethodInfo
is enough.

Comment: I recommended that, but I posted the other method because that was the question.

@Daniel A. White, You can. You either have to know the name of the class that defines the extension method, or look for it by checking for `ExtensionAttribute`. The way I've found is short is to navigate through the assemblies types and check if they have any types with `ExtensionAttribute`. If it does, I can look at its methods and check to see if the first `ParameterType` is the class it is supposed to extend (ie. `static void Foo(this Program)`) we would be looking for `Program` as the `ParameterType`

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested to see a code snippet I posted in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496602/254025):

It's a more general way to get any generic method via an extension method, with clean syntax that looks like:

```
var where = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(
  "Where", 
  typeof(IQueryable<Refl.T1>), 
  typeof(Expression<Func<Refl.T1, bool>>
);
```

Notice the `Refl.T1` that takes the place of a generic type parameter.