# How to get MethodInfo for generic extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, extension-methods

I have an `IEnumerable<T>`, and I want to call the [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method by reflection.  I'm just struggling to get the syntax right.  Here's what I currently have:

```
var containsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Contains", 
  new[] {
    typeof(IEnumerable<T>), 
    typeof(T) 
  });
```

This just comes back with a null.

What is the correct way to get the `MethodInfo`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the correct way to get the MethodInfo?

You have to find the *generic* method - which is unfortunately a bit of a pain - and then construct that with the appropriate arguments. In this case you know that there are only 2 `Contains` overloads, and the one you want has two arguments, so you can use:

```
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                               .Where(m => m.Name == "Contains")
                               .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                               .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
```

You should then be able to invoke it appropriately.

Comment: That's nice code just for this method and this class. In general, there must be more and more checks.

Comment: You may want to fold the check from the `Where` into `Single`, i.e. `m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I personally found it more readable in this form. You *could* fold the check in, sure. This is closer to how I think about it though - find all the Contains methods, then find the one which has the right number of parameters.

Comment: @nsinreal: Yes, in general it's a pain finding generic methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet: hm, I am understanding that there can be nice syntax for generic method choosing. Smth like `GetMethods(types: (Type T) => new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>).WithGenericTypes(T), T })` - through expressions. How do you think, is there real need of such syntax? Can it be writed more better?

Comment: @nsinreal: I think it comes up sufficiently rarely for it not to be too bad to just use the kind of code I've given.