# Get OrderBy method using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, expression-trees

I want to implement generic pager and filter View Model for my project and I'm stuck on getting OrderBy method using reflection. Here is what I've tried, but keep getting `null` for `methodInfo`. It seems I'm passing the wrong `Type[]` arguments to the `GetMethod()` Method, but I can't get it right.

```
    protected virtual Expression<Func<T, IComparable>> GetOrderByExpression()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty("DataSetName");
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OrderBy", new Type[] { orderByExp.Body.Type });
        var predicateBody = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, methodInfo, orderByExp);
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IComparable>>(predicateBody, parameter);

        return expression;
    }
```

Comment: As `OrderBy` is an extension method I'm not sure it will exist in that context.

Comment: [This question, and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570910/reflection-how-to-get-methodinfo-for-generic-extension-method) appears to have the appropriate information to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then `Enumerable.OrderBy` extension method is a static method so you have to use an overload to `GetMethod` where you can specify `BindingFlags` (`BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public` instead of the default `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public`).

You also have to specify two parameters to the method - syntactically it looks like there is only one parameter but because it is an extension method there is a second parameter which you have to specify.

This is the method you want to get via reflection:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

You need the two parameter types:

```
var sourceType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var keySelectorType = orderByExp.Compile().GetType();
```

It seems that the only way to get a specific overload of a method with generic parameters you have to perform a search. Fortunately, there are only two overloads of `Enumerable.OrderBy` and the one you want is the one with two parameters:

```
var genericMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
  .First(mi => mi.Name == "OrderBy" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);
var methodInfo = genericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, keySelectorType);
```

This returns the desired `MethodInfo`, however you will have to modify the remaining two lines of code because this method is a static method and you have to specify a null instance in `Expression.Call`.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I was able to get the desired 'OrderBy' method.