# How to verify that a Type can be passed to a generic method in C# also restore generic parameter types based on passed arguments

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

Let me try to explain what I mean. For example I have the following code:

```
public static class MyClass
{
   public static void DoSmthWithCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Of course, compiler would allow to pass to it an object of `List<int>` type. Moreover, the compiler will figure out that the type `T` for the method is resolved to `int` type based on the argument type.

I need to do the same only dynamically, either by using System.Reflection or Roslyn. Say I get the `MethodInfo` for the method, I get the generic `ParameterInfo`. Is there any easy way to figure out that an object of type `typeof(List<int>)` actually fits to be an argument to the method and that when you pass it, the method resolves `T` to `int` type? And I am talking about some relatively easy solution without examining types and subtypes and the generic type constraints. I think at least Roslyn should have one, since this is what the C# compiler is doing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection?

Comment: Or are you essentially asking; Given a `MethodInfo` and an `object[]` of argument values, how do I discover the `Type[]` I need to pass to `.MakeGenericMethod()` so I can then call `Invoke`?

Comment: I do not think it is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection. It is not about overloading - the generic `MethodInfo` is assumed known. One can have a method with multiple Generic Parameters and multiple arguments. The arguments might not map 1-to-1 into generic parameters, e.g. 
    `public static void DoSmth<T1, T2, T3>(IDictionary<T1, T2> dictionary, T3 anotherVar)`
Given a concrete type (not an object but a type) I want to see if it can serve as an argument for the dictionary and, if yes, which concrete types T1 and T2 will become

Comment: To clarify, assume that we have generic MethodInfo for a generic method `public static void DoSmth<T1, T2, T3>(IDictionary<T1, T2> dictionary, T3 anotherVar)`. Perhaps the generic type have some constraints. Then I have a concrete type, say `typeof(Dictionary<int, double>)`. I want to answer two questions: 1. Can objects of this type serve as `dictionary` argument of the method? In the sample above, the answer is 'yes' unless we add some constraints. 2. If yes, what will it force T1 and T2 args to be? In the above sample obviously it is `int` and `double`, but I want a generic answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it simple, but I've written something that seems to work.

```cs
        private IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypes(Type t)
        {
            do
            {
                yield return t;
                t = t.BaseType;
            } while (t != null);
        }


            var method = new Action<IEnumerable<object>>(MyClass.DoSmthWithCollection).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
            var testParms = new Type[] { typeof(List<int>) };

            var methodParms = method.GetParameters();
            var methodTypes = method.GetGenericArguments();
            var actualTypes = new Type[methodTypes.Length];

            for (var parmIndex = 0; parmIndex < methodParms.Length; parmIndex++)
            {
                var methodParmType = methodParms[parmIndex].ParameterType;
                if (!methodParmType.ContainsGenericParameters)
                    continue;

                var methodParmBaseType = methodParmType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                var testParmType = testParms[parmIndex];
                IEnumerable<Type> compareTypes = methodParmType.IsInterface ? testParmType.GetInterfaces() : BaseTypes(testParmType);
                var match = compareTypes.Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == methodParmBaseType).Single();
                var testArgs = match.GetGenericArguments();
                var parmArgs = methodParmType.GetGenericArguments();
                for (var i = 0; i < parmArgs.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (parmArgs[i].IsGenericMethodParameter)
                    {
                        for(var idx = 0; idx < methodTypes.Length; idx++)
                            if (methodTypes[idx] == parmArgs[i])
                            {
                                actualTypes[idx] = testArgs[i];
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(actualTypes);
```

I hope there's an easier way, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I do not mind it being not simple and even not performant - it is not something that my program has to call often.

Comment: I tried, it works indeed on the example at the top, but it already stops working on the example later in the comments containing `IDictionary<T1, T2>` as a parameter. I am looking if it can be modified to become more generic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with an ok solution, using some ideas from Jeremy Lakeman's example below. It even takes constraints into consideration (though I think it would crash on recursive constraints).

```
    public static bool CheckConcreteTypeSatisfiesGenericParamConstraints(this Type concreteType, Type genericParamType)
    {
        bool hasReferenceTypeConstraint = genericParamType.GenericParameterAttributes.HasFlag(GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint);
        bool hasNewConstraint =
            genericParamType.GenericParameterAttributes.HasFlag(GenericParameterAttributes.DefaultConstructorConstraint);

        bool isNonNullable = genericParamType.GenericParameterAttributes.HasFlag(GenericParameterAttributes.NotNullableValueTypeConstraint);

        if (hasReferenceTypeConstraint)
        {
            if (concreteType.IsValueType)
                return false;
        }
        else if (isNonNullable && !concreteType.IsValueType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (hasNewConstraint)
        {
            ConstructorInfo constrInfo = concreteType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

            if (constrInfo != null)
                return false;
        }

        Type[] constraintTypes = genericParamType.GetGenericParameterConstraints();

        if (constraintTypes == null)
            return true;

        Type[] concreteTypeSuperTypes = concreteType.GetSelfSuperTypesAndInterfaces().Distinct().ToArray();

        foreach(Type constraintType in constraintTypes)
        {
            if (!concreteTypeSuperTypes.Contains(constraintType))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetSelfSuperTypesAndInterfaces(this Type type)
    {
        if (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
        }

        if (type.BaseType != null)
        {
            foreach (var superType in type.BaseType.GetSelfSuperTypesAndInterfaces())
            {
                yield return superType;
            }
        }

        foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            foreach (var superInterface in interfaceType.GetSelfSuperTypesAndInterfaces())
            {
                yield return superInterface;
            }
        }
    }

    public class GenericParamInfo
    {
        public Type GenericParamType { get; }

        public Type ConcreteType { get; set; }

        public GenericParamInfo(Type genericParamType)
        {
            GenericParamType = genericParamType;
        }
    }

    // returns false if cannot resolve
    public static bool ResolveType
    (
        this Type argToResolveType, 
        Type genericArgType, 
        IEnumerable<GenericParamInfo> genericTypeParamsToConcretize)
    {
        if (genericArgType.IsGenericParameter)
        {
            GenericParamInfo foundParamInfo = genericTypeParamsToConcretize.Single(t => t.GenericParamType == genericArgType);

            if (!argToResolveType.CheckConcreteTypeSatisfiesGenericParamConstraints(foundParamInfo.GenericParamType))
            {
                return false;
            }

            foundParamInfo.ConcreteType = argToResolveType;

            return true;
        }
        else if (genericArgType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var matchingSuperType =
                argToResolveType.GetSelfSuperTypesAndInterfaces()
                                .Distinct()
                                .Where(arg => arg.IsGenericType)
                                .Single(arg => arg.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericArgType.GetGenericTypeDefinition());

            if (matchingSuperType == null)
                return false;

            Type[] concreteArgs = matchingSuperType.GetGenericArguments();
            Type[] genericArgs = genericArgType.GetGenericArguments();

            foreach((Type concrArgType, Type genArgType) in concreteArgs.Zip(genericArgs, (c, g) => (c, g)))
            {
                if (!concrArgType.ResolveType(genArgType, genericTypeParamsToConcretize))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Below, I show how to test it on 3 methods = `DoSmth1<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> collection)`, `DoSmth2<T>(T val)` and `DoSmth3<T>(IEnumerable<T> val)`:

```
    public static void DoSmth1<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> collection)
        where T2 : struct
    {

    }

    public static void DoSmth2<T>(T val)
    {

    }

    public static void DoSmth3<T>(IEnumerable<T> val)
    {

    }

    static (bool, GenericParamInfo[]) TestResolveMethodType(Type argToResolve, string methodName)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod(methodName);

        //assuming that we always try to resolve the first method parameter for simplicity
        Type genericArgType = methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

        GenericParamInfo[] typesToConcretize =
            methodInfo.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => new GenericParamInfo(t)).ToArray();

        bool result = argToResolve.ResolveType(genericArgType, typesToConcretize);

        return (result, typesToConcretize);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (bool result1, GenericParamInfo[] concretizedTypes1) = 
            TestResolveMethodType(typeof(Dictionary<int, double>), nameof(DoSmth1));

        (bool result2, GenericParamInfo[] concretizedTypes2) =
            TestResolveMethodType(typeof(int), nameof(DoSmth2));

        (bool result3, GenericParamInfo[] concretizedTypes3) =
            TestResolveMethodType(typeof(List<int>), nameof(DoSmth3));
    }
```